# Set-Service control actions

Tags: powershell, service

I am using below command to start the windows service. I need stop the execution of this command if it doesn't start before 5 or 10 and continue with next commands in script. Can you please help me how do it?

```
Get-Service -ComputerName “$server_name” -Name “XHedge.Execution-NYTRADER” |
    Set-Service -Status Running
```

Comment: Please avoid starting (or stopping) a service via `Set-Service -Status`. Use `Start-Service` and `Stop-Service` respectively. The cmdlets are running synchronously and starting services has a default timeout of 30 seconds. Does that not suffice?

Comment: I am starting service on remote server not on local server...is it fine if i use start-service for remote server.

Comment: The cmdlets should work for remote hosts as well (reading `Get-Service` output from the pipeline), but I'm not sure if they run synchronously in that situation. If they don't you'll need to check the service state in a loop until your timeout is reached.